# Flask WTForm SelectField producing 404 error

Tags: python, flask, http-status-code-404, wtforms

I have spent hours at this do not know why I am getting a 404 error. I will try to be as clear as possible.
This is my folder structure.

```
project-->
       run.py
       app-->
            forms.py
            views.py
            templates-->
                       Crew.html
            static-->
                    Crews-->
                            1901.json
                            1902.json
                            1903.json
```

In forms.py this is how the form is created and populated

```
    import os
from flask import current_app
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import SelectField


class CrewForm(Form):
    filename = SelectField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        root = os.path.join(current_app.static_folder, 'Crews')
        choices = [(f, f) for f in os.listdir(root) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root, f))]
        self.filename.kwargs['choices'] = choices
        super(CrewForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

In views.py this is is the @app.route

```
@app.route('/CastCrew', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def crew():
    form = CrewForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return current_app.send_static_file(os.path.join('Crews', form.filename.data))

    return render_template('Crew.html', form=form)
```

And in Crew.html this is how the form is created

```
<form method="post">
  {{ form.hidden_tag() }} <!--CSFR config -->
      Please choose a year:<br>
      {{ form.filename }}<br>
```

I have javascript code that calls the /CastCrew function to receive the data,

```
d3.json("/CastCrew", function(error, graph) {
```

When I choose a year, and press Submit, in the cmd prompt I get this error - `POST /CastCrew HTTP/1.1 404-`

And on the web page i get this error

```
Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

If the form is populating correctly why am I getting a 404 error? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Am getting this error message in web console**

```
The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The `document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.`
```

run.py

```
from app import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

added `print(app.url_map)` to end of run.py and got this

```
    * Restarting with reloader
Map([<Rule '/CastCrew' (HEAD, POST, OPTIONS, GET) -> crew>,
 <Rule '/index' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> index>,
 <Rule '/about' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> about>,
 <Rule '/data' (HEAD, POST, OPTIONS, GET) -> data>,
 <Rule '/' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> index>,
 <Rule '/static/<filename>' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> static>])
```

This question was marked as a duplicate, and links to a previous question I asked - it is different because it was edited by another user as another problem arose, making it different.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `POST` as your method for the form since you aren't persisting anything. `GET` requests can come with data to specify what you want back form the server.

Comment: In `run.py` after you register your routes, what is the output of `print(app.url_map)`?

Comment: @Sean Vieira  I've added that to the question :)

Answer (score 1):

***If*** you are on Windows, I think your major problem is a missing `/` character

In this line

```
return current_app.send_static_file(os.path.join('Crews', form.filename.data))
```

on Windows, `os.path.join('Crews', form.filename.data)` will create a path with the Windows separator i.e. `Crews\<filename>.json` which then gets prepended with the host name.  However, you need a URL style sub path i.e. `Crews/<filename>.json`.

You should join `Crews/` with the filename, not `Crews`. The 404 is telling you it can't find that file to return (because the path is invalid).  There may be other bugs as we don't know the complete setup of your `run.py` etc.

Try this line instead

```
return current_app.send_static_file(os.path.join('Crews/', form.filename.data))
```

Comment: added the '\' and it didn't make a difference, I've added the run.py code to the question now :)

Comment: Note the direction of the slash.

Comment: sorry typo, meant to write a "/"

Comment: OK well, I'm out. There are many potential issues here and without an Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example it's hard to help. I've a version that does what I think you want on my machine, but it needed the `/` correction, also changed the name of folder `app` to `myapp` to avoid confusion with your `app` `Flask` object, made assumptions on your imports, added an action `CrewCast` to your form (so as not to complicate with `d3` javascript).  You need to make an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and describe the debugging you've tried, which line is failing etc....

Comment: By the way - you now have a working example on the other question (nominated as duplicate), which makes all the corrections mentioned in the comment above and (probably) more besides.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like at least part of your problem might be indentation. You have:

```
@app.route('/CastCrew', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def crew():
    form = CrewForm()

if form.validate_on_submit():
    return current_app.send_static_file(os.path.join('Crews', form.filename.data))

return render_template('Crew.html', form=form)
```

When it should be:

```
@app.route('/CastCrew', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def crew():
    form = CrewForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return current_app.send_static_file(os.path.join('Crews', form.filename.data))

    return render_template('Crew.html', form=form)
```

With the form submit code inside the `crew()` function.

Comment: Sorry Rory I must've indented that wrong when pasting the code, it's indented correctly in the file :)

Comment: Ah, sorry! My mistake! :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use javascripts?

I modified your code a bit and it worked fine for me.

Crew.html

```
<form method="post">
   {{ form.hidden_tag() }} <!--CSFR config -->
   Please choose a year:<br>
   {{ form.filename }}<br>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Views.py

```
from app import app

@app.route('/CastCrew', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
   def crew():
      form = CrewForm()
      if form.validate_on_submit():
         return app.send_static_file(os.path.join('Crews', form.filename.data))
      return render_template('Crew.html', form=form)
```

If this does not help, you need to track down the issue better. The not found error indicates that a file is not located where you think it is. Add some logging or prints that helps you locate which line causes the crash.

Comment: That code is same as what I have except for the indentation of def Crew():? The file is located there the form is being populated with the names of the files in the Crews folder, could it have something to do with encoding?